# How to enumerate months in a View

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSql table that contains, among others, the following columns:

```
…
estimate_close_date           date,
duration_months               int,
…
```

I have to create a View object from the table that generates a row for every month between (estimate_close_date + 1) and (estimate_close_date + duration_months). An example:

estimate_close_date = ‘2022-10-01’ and duration_months = 2

The result should be 2 rows: for ‘2022-11-01’ and ‘2022-12-01’

How can I implement it in a View ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `generate_series` to generate the needed rows and lateral join to correlate them to your table.

```sql
select t.*, gs::date 
from the_table t
cross join lateral generate_series
(
 estimate_close_date + interval '1 month', 
 estimate_close_date + duration_months * interval '1 month', 
 interval '1 month'
) gs
order by estimate_close_date, gs;
```

DB-fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jFXPLA2gyU69c59EhvMLXf/0)